# Как правильно умножить матрицу на другую матрицу в нескольких потоках?

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика, матрицы

Моя задача такая. Мне нужно параллельно на 8 потоках умножить матрицу 200x248 на матрицу 248x333. В интернете я нашел простой пример умножения двух матриц 4x4 на 4 потоках, но я не совсем понимаю логику разделения этой задачи между потоками. Почему у каждого потока разные границы циклов и как они вообще образовываются? Почему в каждом потоке аж 3 цикла, а не 2? Можете мне объяснить алгоритм, чтобы я мог по его аналогии сделать умножение огромных матриц на 8 потоках?

Вот часть этого кода (там еще есть ввод данных с файла и вывод результата в другой файл, графический интерфейс и другое, но это не столь важно в этом вопросе).

Инициализация статических полей:

```
public static int[][] a;
public static int[][] b;
public static int[][] c;
```

Где-то в main создаются и запускаются потоки:

```
            c = new int[a.length][b[0].length];

            Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1();
            Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2();
            Thread3 thread3 = new Thread3();
            Thread4 thread4 = new Thread4();

            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
            thread4.start();

            try {
                thread1.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                thread2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                thread3.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                thread4.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Код четырех потоков:

```
public static class Thread1 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int m = a.length;
        int n = b[0].length;
        int k = (a.length) / 4;

        for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < b.length; l++) {
                    c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][l] * b[l][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Thread2 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int m = a.length;
        int n = b[0].length;
        int k = (a.length) / 2 + 1;
        int s = ((a.length) / 4) + 1;

        for (int i = s; i < k; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < b.length; l++) {
                    c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][l] * b[l][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Thread3 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int m = a.length;
        int n = b[0].length;
        int k = ((3 * (a.length)) / 4) + 1;
        int s = (a.length) / 2 + 1;

        for (int i = s; i < k; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < b.length; l++) {
                    c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][l] * b[l][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Thread4 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int m = a.length;
        int n = b[0].length;
        int k = ((3 * (a.length)) / 4) + 1;


        for (int i = k; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          for (int l = 0; l < b.length; l++) {
                        c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][l] * b[l][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Умножить в одном потоке можете? Проход в цикле по всем строкам/столбцам должен быть?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в одном потоке могу, но задача стоит для 8 потоков. Как я понимаю, мне нужно разделить матрицу на 8 частей и каждую часть обрабатывать отдельным потоком, но я не могу понять как это сделать...

Comment: Я не помню специфику умножения матриц, вскользь читал про нее. Но, например, нужно пройти по всем столбцам матрицы 200x248, которых 248. 248/8 = 31, следовательно каждый поток обрабатывает только 31 столбец. 0-31, 32-63 и так далее.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а с этим кодом что? Он работает правильно, я проверял, но я не могу понять как работают эти циклы...точнее мне важнее понять полный алгоритм, чтобы использовать его под свою задачу.

Comment: Они там как раз и выбирают какой диаппазон обрабатывать в каждом потоке.

Comment: Если я правильно помню умножение матриц, то значение c[i,j] - скалярное произведение строки a[i] на столбец b[j], т.е. внутренний цикл. Остальные два просто перебирают a[i,j]. Вы уверены, что это хороший код, с четырьмя классами, отличающимися только диапазоном по `i`?

Comment: Рекомендую вам не хардкодить число `8`, а оставить его в качестве настраиваемого параметра. Тогда ваш код сможет оптимально работать и на четырех, и на 16ти ядрах.

Comment: Странный код. IMHO должна быть одна функция, запускаемая в N (у Вас 8) потоках, получающая ссылки на матрицы и индексы строк (2 числа -- начало и конец) результирующей матрицы (C[i][j]), которые она считает. При Ваших размерах 200х248 248х333 200х333 (это размер результата) все займет около 1М и замечательно поместится в кэш "стандартного" CPU.

Comment: @zRrr ну я и не говорил, что это хороший код :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Полная тестовая программа, вычисляющая произведение матриц в несколько потоков. В отличие от предложенного в другом ответе варианта, распределяет вычисления между потоками более "справедливо". Поток не обязательно вычисляет строку новой матрицы целиком, вычисления могут начинаться и заканчиваться на любой ячейке матрицы.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

/** Поток-вычислитель группы ячеек матрицы. */
class MultiplierThread extends Thread
{
    /** Первая (левая) матрица. */
    private final int[][] firstMatrix;
    /** Вторая (правая) матрица. */
    private final int[][] secondMatrix;
    /** Результирующая матрица. */
    private final int[][] resultMatrix;
    /** Начальный индекс. */
    private final int firstIndex;
    /** Конечный индекс. */
    private final int lastIndex;
    /** Число членов суммы при вычислении значения ячейки. */
    private final int sumLength;

    /**
     * @param firstMatrix  Первая (левая) матрица.
     * @param secondMatrix Вторая (правая) матрица.
     * @param resultMatrix Результирующая матрица.
     * @param firstIndex   Начальный индекс (ячейка с этим индексом вычисляется).
     * @param lastIndex    Конечный индекс (ячейка с этим индексом не вычисляется).
     */
    public MultiplierThread(final int[][] firstMatrix,
                            final int[][] secondMatrix,
                            final int[][] resultMatrix,
                            final int firstIndex,
                            final int lastIndex)
    {
        this.firstMatrix  = firstMatrix;
        this.secondMatrix = secondMatrix;
        this.resultMatrix = resultMatrix;
        this.firstIndex   = firstIndex;
        this.lastIndex    = lastIndex;

        sumLength = secondMatrix.length;
    }

    /**Вычисление значения в одной ячейке.
     *
     * @param row Номер строки ячейки.
     * @param col Номер столбца ячейки.
     */
    private void calcValue(final int row, final int col)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sumLength; ++i)
            sum += firstMatrix[row][i] * secondMatrix[i][col];
        resultMatrix[row][col] = sum;
    }

    /** Рабочая функция потока. */
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Thread " + getName() + " started. Calculating cells from " + firstIndex + " to " + lastIndex + "...");

        final int colCount = secondMatrix[0].length;  // Число столбцов результирующей матрицы.
        for (int index = firstIndex; index < lastIndex; ++index)
            calcValue(index / colCount, index % colCount);

        System.out.println("Thread " + getName() + " finished.");
    }
}

class Main
{
    /** Заполнение матрицы случайными числами.
     *
     * @param matrix Заполняемая матрица.
     */
    private static void randomMatrix(final int[][] matrix)
    {
        final Random random = new Random();  // Генератор случайных чисел.

        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; ++row)           // Цикл по строкам матрицы.
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; ++col)  // Цикл по столбцам матрицы.
                matrix[row][col] = random.nextInt(100);         // Случайное число от 0 до 100.
    }

    //

    /** Вывод матрицы в файл.
     * Производится выравнивание значений для лучшего восприятия.
     *
     * @param fileWriter Объект, представляющий собой файл для записи.
     * @param matrix Выводимая матрица.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static void printMatrix(final FileWriter fileWriter,
                                    final int[][] matrix) throws IOException
    {
        boolean hasNegative = false;  // Признак наличия в матрице отрицательных чисел.
        int     maxValue    = 0;      // Максимальное по модулю число в матрице.

        // Вычисляем максимальное по модулю число в матрице и проверяем на наличие отрицательных чисел.
        for (final int[] row : matrix) {  // Цикл по строкам матрицы.
            for (final int element : row) {  // Цикл по столбцам матрицы.
                int temp = element;
                if (element < 0) {
                    hasNegative = true;
                    temp = -temp;
                }
                if (temp > maxValue)
                    maxValue = temp;
            }
        }

        // Вычисление длины позиции под число.
        int len = Integer.toString(maxValue).length() + 1;  // Одно знакоместо под разделитель (пробел).
        if (hasNegative)
            ++len;  // Если есть отрицательные, добавляем знакоместо под минус.

        // Построение строки формата.
        final String formatString = "%" + len + "d";

        // Вывод элементов матрицы в файл.
        for (final int[] row : matrix) {  // Цикл по строкам матрицы.
            for (final int element : row)  // Цикл по столбцам матрицы.
                fileWriter.write(String.format(formatString, element));

            fileWriter.write("\n");  // Разделяем строки матрицы переводом строки.
        }
    }

    /**
     * Вывод трёх матриц в файл. Файл будет перезаписан.
     *
     * @param fileName     Имя файла для вывода.
     * @param firstMatrix  Первая матрица.
     * @param secondMatrix Вторая матрица.
     * @param resultMatrix Результирующая матрица.
     */
    private static void printAllMatrix(final String fileName,
                                       final int[][] firstMatrix,
                                       final int[][] secondMatrix,
                                       final int[][] resultMatrix)
    {
        try (final FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, false)) {
            fileWriter.write("First matrix:\n");
            printMatrix(fileWriter, firstMatrix);

            fileWriter.write("\nSecond matrix:\n");
            printMatrix(fileWriter, secondMatrix);

            fileWriter.write("\nResult matrix:\n");
            printMatrix(fileWriter, resultMatrix);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Однопоточное умножение матриц.
     *
     * @param firstMatrix  Первая матрица.
     * @param secondMatrix Вторая матрица.
     * @return Результирующая матрица.
     */
    private static int[][] multiplyMatrix(final int[][] firstMatrix,
                                          final int[][] secondMatrix)
    {
        final int rowCount = firstMatrix.length;             // Число строк результирующей матрицы.
        final int colCount = secondMatrix[0].length;         // Число столбцов результирующей матрицы.
        final int sumLength = secondMatrix.length;           // Число членов суммы при вычислении значения ячейки.
        final int[][] result = new int[rowCount][colCount];  // Результирующая матрица.

        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; ++row) {  // Цикл по строкам матрицы.
            for (int col = 0; col < colCount; ++col) {  // Цикл по столбцам матрицы.
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < sumLength; ++i)
                    sum += firstMatrix[row][i] * secondMatrix[i][col];
                result[row][col] = sum;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /** Многопоточное умножение матриц.
     *
     * @param firstMatrix  Первая (левая) матрица.
     * @param secondMatrix Вторая (правая) матрица.
     * @param threadCount Число потоков.
     * @return Результирующая матрица.
     */
    private static int[][] multiplyMatrixMT(final int[][] firstMatrix,
                                            final int[][] secondMatrix,
                                            int threadCount)
    {
        assert threadCount > 0;

        final int rowCount = firstMatrix.length;             // Число строк результирующей матрицы.
        final int colCount = secondMatrix[0].length;         // Число столбцов результирующей матрицы.
        final int[][] result = new int[rowCount][colCount];  // Результирующая матрица.

        final int cellsForThread = (rowCount * colCount) / threadCount;  // Число вычисляемых ячеек на поток.
        int firstIndex = 0;  // Индекс первой вычисляемой ячейки.
        final MultiplierThread[] multiplierThreads = new MultiplierThread[threadCount];  // Массив потоков.

        // Создание и запуск потоков.
        for (int threadIndex = threadCount - 1; threadIndex >= 0; --threadIndex) {
            int lastIndex = firstIndex + cellsForThread;  // Индекс последней вычисляемой ячейки.
            if (threadIndex == 0) {
                /* Один из потоков должен будет вычислить не только свой блок ячеек,
                   но и остаток, если число ячеек не делится нацело на число потоков. */
                lastIndex = rowCount * colCount;
            }
            multiplierThreads[threadIndex] = new MultiplierThread(firstMatrix, secondMatrix, result, firstIndex, lastIndex);
            multiplierThreads[threadIndex].start();
            firstIndex = lastIndex;
        }

        // Ожидание завершения потоков.
        try {
            for (final MultiplierThread multiplierThread : multiplierThreads)
                multiplierThread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /** Число строк первой матрицы. */
    final static int FIRST_MATRIX_ROWS  = 1000;
    /** Число столбцов первой матрицы. */
    final static int FIRST_MATRIX_COLS  = 1000;
    /** Число строк второй матрицы (должно совпадать с числом столбцов первой матрицы). */
    final static int SECOND_MATRIX_ROWS = FIRST_MATRIX_COLS;
    /** Число столбцов второй матрицы. */
    final static int SECOND_MATRIX_COLS = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int[][] firstMatrix  = new int[FIRST_MATRIX_ROWS][FIRST_MATRIX_COLS];    // Первая (левая) матрица.
        final int[][] secondMatrix = new int[SECOND_MATRIX_ROWS][SECOND_MATRIX_COLS];  // Вторая (правая) матрица.

        randomMatrix(firstMatrix);
        randomMatrix(secondMatrix);

        final int[][] resultMatrixMT = multiplyMatrixMT(firstMatrix, secondMatrix, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        // Проверка многопоточных вычислений с помощью однопоточных.
        final int[][] resultMatrix = multiplyMatrix(firstMatrix, secondMatrix);

        for (int row = 0; row < FIRST_MATRIX_ROWS; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < SECOND_MATRIX_COLS; ++col) {
                if (resultMatrixMT[row][col] != resultMatrix[row][col]) {
                    System.out.println("Error in multithreaded calculation!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        printAllMatrix("Matrix.txt", firstMatrix, secondMatrix, resultMatrixMT);
    }
}
```

P.S. Среди особенностей - форматированный вывод матриц в файл и автоматическое определение размера матриц в функциях-вычислителях. В качестве бонуса - однопоточное вычисление и контроль многопоточного результата с помощью однопоточного.

Comment: Я даже не ожидал такого ответа :)

Answer (score 5):

Вот накидал рабочий код:

```
public static class CalcThread extends Thread {
    private int startRow, endRow;
    private int[][] a, b, result;
    private int n;

    public CalcThread(int[][] a, int[][] b, int[][] result, int startRow, int endRow) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.result = result;
        this.startRow = startRow;
        this.endRow = endRow;
        this.n = b.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Считаю со строки " + startRow + " до строки " + endRow + " включительно");
        for (int row = startRow; row <= endRow ; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < result[row].length; col++) {
                result[row][col] = calcSingleValue(row, col);
            }
        }
    }

    private int calcSingleValue(int row, int col) {
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            c += a[row][i] * b[i][col];
        }
        return c;
    }
}

public static int[][] multiply(int[][] a, int[][] b, int threadsCount) {
    //проверки
    if (a == null || a.length == 0 || a[0] == null || a[0].length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("a");
    }
    if (b == null || b.length == 0 || b[0] == null || b[0].length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("b");
    }
    if (a[0].length != b.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("матрицы не согласованы");
    }
    //определяем размеры результирующей матрицы
    int m = a.length;
    int q = b[0].length;
    int[][] result = new int[m][q];
    //если количество потоков больше чем количество строк - уменьшим кол-во потоков
    if (threadsCount > m) {
        threadsCount = m;
    }
    //посчитаем сколько строк результирующей матрицы будет считать каждый поток
    int count = m / threadsCount;
    int additional = m % threadsCount; //если не делится на threadsCount, то добавим к первому потоку
    //создаем и запускаем потоки
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadsCount];
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++) {
        int cnt = ((i == 0) ? count + additional : count);
        threads[i] = new CalcThread(a, b, result, start, start + cnt - 1);
        start += cnt;
        threads[i].start();
    }
    //ждем завершения
    try {
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    int[][] b = {{2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1}};
    int[][] c = multiply(a, b, 8);

    for (int[] ints : c) {
        for (int anInt : ints) {
            System.out.print(anInt + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример :) Я выбрал тот ответ результатом потому, что он более объемный, а два ответа выбрать нельзя, но это решение мне тоже подходит.